# Rollback single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How to rollback the single table in laravel 4.
I ran `php artisan migrate:rollback` to roll back all the migrations but how to rollback the single table

Advice much appreciated

Comment: `php artisan migrate:rollback` rollbacks last migration and `:refresh` does all but there is no command for single specific one, AFAIK.

Comment: [You may check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697247/laravel-4-artisan-how-to-rollback-to-a-specific-migration-state).

Answer (score 10):

for example, you want to create the user table again, just go to mysql and delete from migration's table the field that correspond to TIMESTAMP_create_users_table:

```
DELETE FROM MIGRATIONS WHERE MIGRATION ="2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table";
```

and drop the users table too:

```
DROP TABLE users;
```

after that, just run

```
php artisan migrate
```

and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to rollback only a specific table, you should make a migration that only includes that table. It's really that simple. Making large migrations covering several updates doesn't make any sense.

Create migrations based upon their purpose. That means; on a live project every little code change should have its own related migration.

Answer (score 0):

Just run The command (Laravel 5):-

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5
```

It will undo last 5 migrations (in fact it will execute the function "down" in each one)

```
php artisan migrate
```

It will add all migration table into database