# Migration rollback by file name

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5

I have several migration file .
I want run `php artisan migrate:rollback` by file name like this

```
2016_05_16_131054_create_contries_table.php
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697247/laravel-4-artisan-how-to-rollback-to-a-specific-migration-state?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify migration to rollback. You can only rollback the last migration batch (look `migrations` table).

The best you can do is to make changes in your table with new migration. Or you can save data, rollback all migrations and and migrate again.

Comment: I want to remove this file and drop table and remove fields  from migration table. Is it correct and logical?

Comment: Yes you can drop a table, use `Schema::drop('table');` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables I still think you're missing the point though if you're wanting to remove the file also

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run `php artisan migrate:rollback --path=/database/migrations/migration_filename.php` to rollback a particular migration.

This way, the migration created by that file will be rolled back.